# Overriding CSS to add a "Next" Button to Only Certain Questions in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, css, qualtrics

I have a long survey and for most of the questions, I want the "Previous" and "Next" buttons removed. I achieved this by adding this code to the Custom CSS for the entire survey:

```
#PreviousButton, #NextButton{
   display: none;
}
```

However, I would now like to add a "Next" button to just a few of my questions. Is there a JS I can add to just these questions that will override the Custom CSS and add the "Next" button back in for those specific questions?

Comment: simply add something like `.special-case #NextButton { display: block }` to the CSS and `class="special-case"` to the parent element of the button in specific questions. But read this too: [reprex]

Comment: Okay, so I tried putting this in the CSS code:

`#PreviousButton, #NextButton{
   display: none;
}
.special-case #NextButton { display: block }`

And then this in the JS for an individual question:
`Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
 class="special-case"
});`

But I keep getting an "Unexpected token" error. I'm not a coder (clearly), so thanks for your help and patience!

Comment: In terms of Javascript `{ class="special-case" }` as such makes no sense, hense the error.

Comment: It's okay; I'm not trying to write javascript. Just wondering if there is a code that already exists that can do what I need. This is common in Qualtrics, to copy/paste already written JS into a survey, as it's designed to be usable by non-coders.