# How to hide next button at one page using css and not javascript in Qualtrics?

Tags: css, qualtrics

I have a requirement to remove the next button in a qulatrics survey from one page but not use javascript. As far as I know, we can remove next button using CSS from the whole survey using id selector as follows:

```
#NextButton{
   display: none;
}
```

But when removing it from one page, I was following this thread -

[Overriding CSS to add a "Next" Button to Only Certain Questions in Qualtrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291654/overriding-css-to-add-a-next-button-to-only-certain-questions-in-qualtrics)

It uses a combination of both id and class selector. So I put the CSS as below -

```
.special-case #NextButton { display: none; }
```

And created a div with class "special-case" around my question in HTML pane.

So my question now looks like -

```
<div class = "special-case"> My question in HTML formal </div>
```

I am unsure if this way of combining id and class selector works or not as the next button is not being hidden. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Next button isn't a descendent of a question so that is why "special-case" didn't work.

Add a style tag to a question's text on the pages where you want to hide the Next button:

```
<style>
#NextButton { display: none; }
</style>
```